# SQL Sumar datos de una tabla según condición y registros anteriores

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla ordernada por ***Fecha***, ***Hora*** y la columna ***Orden*** de forma descendente (obligatorio):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero obtener, es una consulta agrupada por fecha y hora que **sume los valores de la columna *Longitud* solo cuando el valor del campo *Velocidad* sea menor a la columna *VelocMinimo***. Teniendo en cuenta que el valor de la columna ***Orden*** debe consecutivo y empezando a sumar desde arriba(por eso ordeno de forma asecendente).

En el siguiente ejemplo solo debería sumar la columna ***Longitud*** de los registros con ***Orden*** 11 y 10 para la hora de 06:20:00 y no debería de tomar el valor del registro con ***IdRegistro*** 14097 (enmarcado en rojo) ya que tiene como valor de ***Orden*** (5) y no es consecutivo con el último valor (10).  Y para la hora 06:25 solo cogería el registro con ***IdRegistro*** 14115 ya que es el único que tiene el valor del campo *Velocidad* menor a la columna ***VelocMinimo***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento he logrado armar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
 Fecha,
 Hora, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN Velocidad<VelocMinimo THEN Longitud ELSE 0 END) SumaLongitud
FROM TB_BASE  
GROUP BY Fecha, Hora
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado (lo cual no es lo que necesito):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Datos adicionales importantes**: Para el ejemplo toda la data le corresponde a un "Tramo" que tiene por Hora-Minuto 11 valores para el campo ***Orden***, pero pueden existir otros que tengan menos o más.

Me sería de mucha ayuda leer sus comentarios. Gracias.

Comment: Los datos se encuentran en el siguiente enlace : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZdUtaCc8Y6RN8McES4MzcR72H3p36Qwdg0g6UVcYPqI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Estuve un par de horas tratando de resolver tu problema, pero se complica mucho si ademas de hacer el Group por Hora y minuto también hay que hacer el Group por el Orden y el ultimo dato que entregas es para complicarlo mas aún ya que no necesariamente deben ser 11 registros, pueden ser mas, el tema es que el select va recorriendo y discriminando en base a un WHERE, pero eso es para la fila en la que va.

Comment: Para efectos de grupo por hora y fecha funciona, pero si ademas debes verificar que sean consecutivos, creo que la única manera de abordar este problema es a través de una función y ahí mantener el dato que cumple y verificar si el siguiente cumple también y si se salta uno ahí salimos de la función.